# round-tripping xml to javascript objects without losing data or corrupting it

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I need to get some XML, convert it to javascript, muck around with it, and convert it back to XML.  I'm working in Node.js.

Currently, if I round trip it from XML to Javascript objects, then back to XML, I end up with a bunch of characters that are screwy (an apostrophe might look like this: â€™ , for example), and CDATA sections are lost.

I've been using xml2js module (also tried xml2js-expat) to read the xml.  The xml labels itself as being UTF-8, and I specify this to xml2js.

To convert back to XML, I am using this:  http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/json2xml.js

But it appears the problem is with the first step.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: To clarify, is it the xml -> JS part is causing you problems or the JS -> xml? Since you are relying on third party solutions either one can be at fault. Also if you could provide a sample XML input and output (the one with the corrupted apostrophe and lack of CDATA) that would help a great deal.